# Dropdown is not working when navbar-fixed-bottom is in collapsed mode(Watching it in Small screens like phone,tablet)

Tags: html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developping Edit Rich Text Editor(JavaScript) using Bootstrap-3. I have decided to put my options like Bold, Italic, Underline in Navbar which is at bottom of the page. I have one dropdown in the Navbar(fixed-Bottom). When I test this in responsive mode with small screen size (mobile, tablet) I am unable to get the options of dropdown which is in Navbar(fixed-bottom). Kindly observe the following code and help me to solve this issue. Thanking you.

```
<div class="container">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#openerp_help_navigation">
        <span class="sr-only"> Toggling the Navigation</span><!-- This is required for screen reader -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Effects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="openerp_help_navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <li><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold" id="btn_bold"></a></li>
        <li><a  href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-italic" id="btn_italic"></a></li>
        <li><a  href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-magnet" id="btn_underline"></a></li>
        <li><a  href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" id="btn_link"></a></li>
        <li><a  href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-order" id="btn_orderd_list"></a></li>            
        <li><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes" id="btn_unorderd_list"></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Font Size <b class="caret"></b>      
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li><a href=""id="btn_text_size_1">1</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_2">2</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_3">3</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_4">4</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_5">5</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_6">6</a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="btn_text_size_7">7</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div id="myEditTextBox" contenteditable="true" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to close anchor tag that has the following class, `dropdown-toggle`. Besides that if that anchor tag has a `href` value other than **#**, the dropdown will not function.

The following code is from official Bootstrap documentation showing how a dropdown is constructed. You can check official documentation for further information - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```